# Motivation for the concept of dimension

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I am currently learning about Hausdorff measure and dimension. In several of the resources I have encountered, the author provides several different definitions of dimension, and they are often presented as precursors to the Hausdorff dimension. For instance, I have encountered the notion of a dimension of a "self-similar" set:

> If a set $E\subseteq X$ can be subdivided into $N\left(s\right)$ subsets that are scaled down versions of $E$ by a factor of $s$, then we define the self-similar dimension of $E$ to be $\dim_{sim}\left(E\right)=\log\left(N\left(s\right)\right)/\log\left(1/s\right)$.

I have also seen the definition of the "box-counting dimension":

> For a bounded subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, partition $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by a regular rid of cubes of side-length $s$ and count how many of them intersect $X$; if this number  is $N\left(s\right)$, then we define the “box-counting dimension” of $X$ to be $\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\log\left(N\left(s\right)\right)/\log\left(1/s\right)$.

The resources I have seen just give the definitions and calculate the dimension of a few sets. What I am struggling to understand is why we are interested in giving these definitions. What exactly are they meant to capture, and what does the "box-cutting" dimension of a set, for instance, tell us about that set?

Comment: Consider the following problem: “define a notion of dimension for a topological space” (or subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$). You will need to find a certain kind of general “numerical” property that gives you the right choice for a cube, or a ball, as well as good compatibilities with product, reunion, subspaces, etc. These definitions are simply different solutions to this problem using different properties of (say) cubes: a $n$-th dimensional cube is the reunion of $2^n$ copy of its scaled down by $1/2$ copy. Box-counting works for “proper subvector spaces”.

Comment: Do you know about the [square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law)? -- Areas scale by the square of the length factor enlargement/reduction and volumes scale by the cube of the length factor enlargement/reduction. This is why insects don't need blood vessels (but we do), and why giant creatures such as [seen in movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_giant_monsters) can't survive (at least on Earth and on land), and why the premise of [this classic TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Giants) is fatally flawed. **(continued)**

Comment: One way to understand the various fractal dimension notions is that they are different ways to capture this idea when the length factor enlargement/reduction of something (length, area, volume, etc.) doesn't scale by an integer (or more generally, doesn't uniformly scale by any value, but instead scales by different values according as to the values of length factor enlargement/reduction).